# Split data into columns, while ignoring leading white space. PERL

Tags: regex, perl, split

Here is a snippet of my raw data:

```
   PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
     1 root      16   0  2160  604  520 S  0.0  0.1   0:01.60 init               
     2 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0        
     3 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0        
     4 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.39 events/0           
     5 root      12  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper            
     6 root      14  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthread            
     9 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.36 kblockd/0          
    10 root      20  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kacpid             
   174 root      14  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cqueue/0           
   177 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khubd
```

Notice how the left column has leading white space. I want to split each column of this data into its own array. That leading white space is what is giving me trouble when using my split function.

I am using this:

```
foreach my $line (@data) {
    my @column = split(/\s+/,$line);
    chomp (@column);
    print "$column[0]\n";

}
```

What I want to have happen when I print all the elements in `column[0]` is it prints all the PID numbers without spaces. When I print `column[1]` it prints all the USERS without spaces. Because the columns are justified right, everything is messed up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is so common a need that the special split invocation `split(' ', ...)` (otherwise identical to `split(/\s+/, ...)`) discards leading whitespace.

Trailing whitespace is discarded by either, so no chomp is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Left trim the string at $line before you split it:

```
#... 
$line =~ s!^\s+!!;
my @column = split(/\s+/,$line);
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Miguel Prz, I had a similar problem where the first element of the array returned an empty value using *split(/\s+/,$line)*. Here's my solution with grep to filter the empty lines using the pattern !/^$/.

```
#... 
my @column = grep {!/^$/} split(/\s+/,$line);
#...
```